# How do I check for a specific color in a Color32 array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to be checking what RGBA a particular index of a Color32 array has. I'm using this in Unity to "read" colors and convert them into functions which I need to use for later. However, Color32 won't accept '==' for an if statement. And a string won't work either.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class SpawnrateGrid : MonoBehaviour {


public Texture2D sourceTex;
Color32[] pix;
int i = 1;


void Start () {
Color32[] pix = sourceTex.GetPixels32();
UnitySystemConsoleRedirector.Redirect();

foreach (Color32 color in pix) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pixel group {0} = {1}", i, color);
    i++;    
        if (string.Equals("RGBA(239, 239, 239, 255)") ){
        }
        if (i>10){
            break;
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code should be throwing the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'string.Equals(string)'`, because `string.Equals("RGBA(239, 239, 239, 255)")` is not valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check color with `name,RGB,RGBA,Conver string to RGB,etc` with all of them with `==` or `!=`, sample code :

```
Color text_color = Color.Black;
            if (text_color == new Color())
            { }

            if (text_color == Color.Transparent)
            { }

            if (text_color != Color.Black)
            { }

            if (text_color != Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255))
            { }

            if (text_color != Color.FromName("Red"))
            { }

            if (text_color == Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Blue))
            { }

            if (text_color == ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66"))
            { }

            if (text_color.R == 255
                && text_color.G == 255
                && text_color.B == 255
                && text_color.A == 0)
            {

            }
```

If you can it's better to use from `ARGB` : (**recommend**)

```
if (text_color != Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255))
{ }
```

Or

```
if (text_color.R == 255
                && text_color.G == 255
                && text_color.B == 255)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Thanks! Checking for the individual RGB colors worked perfectly!

Comment: Well Use from `R,G,B`

Answer (score 1):

Because `Color32` can be [converted into a `Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32-operator_Color32.html), and `Color`, can be [converted into a `Vector4`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-operator_Color.html), you may be able to do this:

```
Vector4 yourColor = new Vector4( 239f, 239f, 239f, 255f ) / 255f ;

foreach (Color32 color in pix)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pixel group {0} = {1}", i, color);
    i++;
    if( ((Vector4) (Color) color) == yourColor )
    {
        // Do something
    }
    if( i > 10 )
    {
        break ;
    }
}
```